# Word order & equivalent sentences

Tags: word-order

I'm learning Esperanto using Duolingo and am a total beginner, so sorry if the questions sound silly. (*Mi estas komencanto!*) I have a bit of a doubt in the following two points:

- Are *Kiel vi fartas?* and *Kiel fartas vi?* both correct? If not, which is, and why?
- Are the following sentences equivalent? *Nedankinde, kara!* , *Vi estas bonvena, kara!* and *Bonvenon, kara!*
  P.S.: Is it wrong to say, *Vi estas bonvenon, kara!*

**Dankon!**

Answer (score 8):

*Kiel vi fartas?* is how you'll usually hear it, but the other word order is OK and means the same thing.

*Nedankinde* is a polite thing to say when someone thanks you.

*Vi estas bonvena* is a way to tell someone that they are welcome somewhere. (You are welcome in my house - vi estas bonvena ĉe mi.)

*Bonvenon* is a way to welcome someone. (Welcome to our house - *Bonvenon ĉe ni*)

Finally, your last sentence is wrong. You don't use -n with *estas*.

Comment: Dankon, @Tomaso Alexander!